# Cucumber: many example rows VS many scenario outlines

Tags: java, cucumber

In terms of best practices, I was wondering if it is better to have a single scenario outline yielding an `Examples` section with many rows or having multiple `scenario outline` instead. E.g:

Since I hate repeated code and my test cases share the same procedure logic, I devised a single scenario with such logic and included one example row for each test case:

```
Scenario Outline: My scenario has many rows in the examples section
  When I perform my request with the following inputs: <param1>, <param2>, ..., <param11>    
Examples:
  | one    | one    | one    | one    | one    | one    | one    | one    | one    | one    | one    |
  | two    | two    | two    | two    | two    | two    | two    | two    | two    | two    | two    |
...
  | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven | eleven |
```

However, I find this approach to be less readable and therefore I was wondering if it would be better to have multiple `scenario outlines` which repeat the same logic, e.g:

```
Scenario Outline: My scenario ONE
   When I perform my request with the specific inputs for test case ONE
   ...
Scenario Outline: My scenario TWO
   When I perform my request with the specific inputs for test case TWO
   ...

Scenario Outline: My scenario ELEVEN
   When I perform my request with the specific inputs for test case ELEVEN
   ...
```

Although I hate repeating myself, I have to say that this approach is much more readable.

Which approach is best practice?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Cucumber is meant to be readable first. Go for readability. Remember, every test --- even a cucumber test --- should only have one reason to fail. This translates to having only one `Then` step in each scenario or scenario outline. Each scenario should handle one ... well... use case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the scenario outline. Which is neat and makes job easy when you have to make a change to the scenario like adding or deleting a step to your scenario.

The only limitation that I see with Scenario Outline approach is `you can't define your own description` for each scenario. However, I think you should be able to handle this by exploring the `runtime options`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean option 1? Could you explain how I could use runtime options for that purpose?

Comment: Yes, I am good with first option. I have to check the runtime options regarding the scenario description update in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest avoiding scenario outlines completely. When writing tests clarity is far more important than being DRY.

As supputuri pointed out in his answer using Scenario Outlines means that you can't define your own scenario for each example. This is a a critical failure. It means that you have to infer the description from the values provided by the example row. If you want that inference to be reliable then you have to add extra fields to the example rows which makes the row more complicated. If you want the row to be simple, then you have to deal with ambiguity.

Each example row should be testing something specific and useful to the business, and if that is the case our scenario should be describing that WHAT and WHY of this thing, not obfuscating the thing in a set of examples.

So does this mean there is no place for examples in Cucumber - well not quite.

Examples are really useful for initiating the process of writing scenarios, and they can be used with great effect in discussion to illustrate a requirement. But as you start implementing and your understanding of the scope and detail of your functionality increases each example needs to mature into a specific scenario, and going through this process you will gain a much better understanding of your problem domain which in turn will help you write better code.

This article, that I wrote many years ago goes into more detail, http://pages.andrew.premdas.org/2011/06/27/composable-features-and-tables.html